# C# compilation error of a console program - no 'Main' method suitable

Tags: c#

I have the following C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace command
{
    class Program
    {

        public string DecryptStr(string _source, string _key)
        {
            string str;
            try
            {
                byte[] bytes1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_key.Substring(0, 8));
                byte[] bytes2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_key.Substring(8, 8));
                DES des = (DES)new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
                des.Key = bytes1;
                des.IV = bytes2;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[_source.Length / 2];
                for (int index = 0; index < _source.Length / 2; ++index)
                {
                    int int32 = Convert.ToInt32(_source.Substring(index * 2, 2), 16);
                    buffer[index] = (byte)int32;
                }
                MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream((Stream)memoryStream, des.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                cryptoStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                str = Encoding.Default.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
                memoryStream.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
                str = "Key Error...";
            }
            return str;
        }

        public void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string decrypted = this.DecryptStr(args[0], "0BDFC73BC56346AA");
            Console.WriteLine(decrypted);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know any C# but seems syntax OK from the point of view of a Ruby/Python programmer. Unfortunately I'm not right, when I try to compile it I get the following error:

```
------ Build started: Project: Decrypt, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
CSC : error CS5001: Program 'c:\Users\John\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Decrypt\Decrypt\obj\Debug\Decrypt.exe' does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: The clue is in the error message: "does not contain a **static** `Main` method"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main method should be `static`. In your code it is not.

See for example default generated when creating a console application:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

---

Furthermore, you can't then use `this.DecryptStr` as it is a static class. You have two options:

1. Create an instance of `Program` and then call its method.
2. Change method to be static too (and still not to use `this`)

Comment: Yes but then I get this: `Keyword 'this' is not valid in a static property, static method, or static field initializer` at `this.DecryptStr`, how should I call the function without `this`?

Comment: make DecryptStr method static as well and call it directly
public static string DecryptStr()

and remove the this. in your Main()

Comment: Yes! Works now. `string decrypted = Program.DecryptStr(args[0], "0BDFC73BC56346AA");`

Comment: @bsteo - I do recommend going through some C# tutorials... Happy it works for you now

Comment: I will. Never needed though.

Comment: @bsteo - Please consider marking question as solved once the 15 minutes pass

Comment: @bsteo a good C# tutorial Ive used is [Scott Lily's Guide to C#](http://scottlilly.com/learn-c-by-building-a-simple-rpg-index/), you'll learn all the basics and build a pretty neat rpg game in the process.